# Execute custom script when an interface gets connected

Tags: ubuntu, debian, networking

I using a USB wifi dongle to connect to the Internet. When the wireless connection dies, I lose some iproute rules too.

How can I reset these rules when the interface connected again?

Comment: Look into [udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Writing_udev_rules).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have `ifupdown` (most likely if you are using Debian or a Debian-based distro) look at `man interfaces`:

```
   post-up command
          Run command after bringing the interface up.  If this command fails then ifup aborts, refraining from marking the interface as  con‐
          figured  (even though it has really been configured), prints an error message, and exits with status 0.  This behavior may change in
          the future.
```

So in `/etc/network/interfaces` you can have something like

```
auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp
    post-up /usr/local/sbin/my-custom-script
```

Replace eth0 for your actual interface.